# Can someone get the source code if it's not "verified"?

Tags: solidity, ether, etherscan

my question is: When I deploy contracts on ropsten or other networks but do not verify the source code (make it public with it), can then someone still see my source code? I know, that function calls will be public but I mean if the whole source code will still be readable in any way. Thanks for answers!

Comment: The bytecode is public, so it can always be read/decompiled (with some difficulty).

Comment: How can I decompile from bytecode to sourcecode/ generally code?

Comment: `porosity` is the only Solidity decompiler I'm aware of, though there may be others.